# Prevent class properties to be null when instantiating a Dart class

Tags: dart

Assuming I have this Dart class:

```
class Stock {
  int id;
  String externalCode;
  String internalCode;
  String name;
  double quantity;
}
```

When I create a new instance of this object like `Stock item = new Stock();` all the properties are `null`.

I know this is a Dart specific behavior, but when sending such objects to an API, since most backend languages like C#, Java etc. don't have nullable primitives exceptions occur when parsing to a corresponding model class.

What is the simplest approach to prevent `int`, `double` and `bool` properties of being `null` (set them to `0`, `0.0` and `false` respectively)  when instantiating a Dart class?

Since many classes might have a lot of properties, a hardwired instantiation like `Stock item = new Stock(id: 0, quantity: 0 /*...and so on... */);` it's out of the question.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a default value for members in a class you can just assign each member to a value in the class definition:

```
class Stock {
  int id = 0;
  String externalCode = "";
  String internalCode = "";
  String name = "";
  double quantity = 0.0;
}
```

Alternative, you can also give default values to optional parameters like:

```
class Stock {
  int id;
  String externalCode;
  String internalCode;
  String name;
  double quantity;

  Stock(
      {this.id = 0,
      this.externalCode = '',
      this.internalCode = '',
      this.name = '',
      this.quantity = 0.0});
}
```